# Leibniz Integral Rule for the indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Can I use the Leibniz Integral Rule for the following indefinite integral?
$$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial s \partial t}[\int |f(x)+ t g(x) + s h(x)|dx]^{2}|_{s=t=0}$$
where $f,g,h:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are the differentiable maps and $s,t\in \mathbb{R}$ .

Thank you for your help.